# Attempt to read property &quot;created_at&quot; on null in

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The following are the function that I am trying to make work. I think I have the information required correct and the corresponding data also exist in the table but it is showing the error as above. Below are the function in my **UserProfileController**.

I've tried to change the column name from created_at to date_checkIn but it is showing the same error, both the columns exist in the database table as shown in my screenshots above. Please help

```
public function userClockOut(Request $r)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";

        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'date_checkIn', 'time_checkOut', 'location_checkOut'])->first();

        $tt = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt);
        $tt2 = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt2);

        $tz = $tt->created_at;
        $tz2 = $tt2->updated_at;

        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tz, 'UTC');
        $time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $tz2, 'UTC');
        $date->setTimezone('Asia/Singapore');
        $time->setTimezone('Asia/Singapore');

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkOut = $time;
        $users->location_checkOut = $r->location_checkOut;

        // Save the updated data to the database
        AttendanceRecord::updateOrCreate(
            ['staff_id' => $users->staff_id, 'date_checkIn' => $date],
            $users->toArray()
        );

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

Screenshots to show that the column exist in the database table :

`https://paste.pics/f6103e8822c01f26bd23d500e0b0e9ad  https://paste.pics/008df0256fd5ec20caff3772194cc0cf https://paste.pics/66cca657a49944e8087451c3b75967d3`

Comment: Are you sure error is not coming from this statement `$tz = $tt->created_at;` ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `$tt = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt);` doesn't return any value so its throwing an error. To solve this first you need to make sure that the `$r->tt` has a value and that value exists in the database. Next is to avoid that error instead of using the `find()` method you should use the `findOrFail()` which will return a `404` status code if the given id do not exist in the database.

```
$tt = AttendanceRecord::findOrFail($r->tt);
$tt2 = AttendanceRecord::findOrFail($r->tt2);
```

Also make sure that the `$r->tt` is the primary key of the table and also make that there's a `tt` attribute in your `form`

Answer (score -1):

`$tt` or `$tt2` doesnot found.

```
$tt = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt);
$tt2 = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt2);
```